# How to change statusbar color

Tags: shell, xamarin.forms

I'm creating an app using Xamarin.Forms Shell, but I can't change the statusbar... I managed to change the color of the activebar but the statusbar remains dark blue.(In an Android Device with Android 9.0 Pie)

[image]

I googled if there's a way to change the color of the status bar, but what I found didn't take effect... so I wonder if in Xamarin.Forms Shell there is a way to change it. otherwise, is there a way in Xamarin.Forms?(without using the shell).

P.S. On https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/configuration

[image]

I see that the iphone has the colored top bar and the device with Android has the status of the black bar, so if one day I will have to use the app in an iphone, does it mean that I will not have this problem? (I assume this also depends on the version of the operating system)

I'd like to read your experience, in the meantime thank you.

Comment: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/124134/how-can-i-change-color-for-statusbar-on-ios-xamarin-forms

Comment: @G.hakim So it only works if I use a NavigationPage?

Comment: Not actually that has nothing to do with navigation page you can do it direct

Comment: @G.hakim What do you mean by directly?

Comment: I changed the color to green in Android(I changed the style.xml), unfortunately I can not test the app with an iPhone for now, but that's okay. Thank you again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please Add 
`Window.SetStatusBarColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Argb(255, 0, 255, 0));` this line in your OnCreate() method of android platform.

[image]

I change the status bar to green.  There is running screenshot.

[image]

Comment: @MyName Are there any updates for this issue? If the reply is helpful, pleasemark it as an answer(Please click ✔ on the top right corner of this answer, the ✔ means mark it answer),  it will help others who have similar issue.